# how to use crontab with &

Tags: linux

I used the crontab to execute a script, while the script had to do some jobs in the background in this format:

```
for i in {1..100}
do
    do_job &
done
```

However, the do_job won't be executed by crontab with &, how to fix this problem.My system is Suse.

Comment: Crontab just spawns a shell and has no idea what the shell is running, so probably the problem is elsewhere. Does the script itself even execute?

Comment: cron is not for running things in the background like this.

Comment: @lgnacio Is there any solutions?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, the script was executed.

Comment: http://keyj.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/run-a-background-process-from-a-crontab/

Comment: Your script contains Bash syntax, does the script file have a valid `#!/bin/bash` shebang line? Does it fail if you run `sh scriptname` from the prompt? Cron jobs run with `sh` unless you explicitly specify Bash.

Comment: Script failures from cron are often due to it having a clean environment that may be missing some environment variables that a program expects. You have to add them back in.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
nohup script.sh 1> /tmp/script.log 2> /tmp/script.err &
```

or use screen (deattached)

```
screen -d -m -S script script.sh;
```

to background processes ([see](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/))

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

```
bash -c "do_job &"
```